# If $ \sum a_n$ converges, does $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\ln n}\cdot \left( n^{a_n}-1 \right)$ converge as well?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> If $ \sum a_n$ converges and $a_n>0$ for every $n$, does $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\ln n}\cdot \left( n^{a_n}-1 \right)$ converge as well?

**What I did:** Define $u_n=\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{\ln n}\cdot \left( n^{a_n}-1 \right)$. Trying to use the ratio test, I consider:
$$ \frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}} \cdot\frac{n^{a_{n+1}}-1}{n^{a_{n}}-1}=\frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}} \cdot\frac{\frac{n^{a_{n+1}}}{n^{a_{n}}}-\frac{1}{n^{a_{n}}}}{1-\frac{1}{n^{a_{n}}}}$$
and now: 
$$ \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} \rightarrow 1 $$
$$ \sqrt{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}} \rightarrow g \in (0;1) $$
but what can I do with the last ratio $$\frac{\frac{n^{a_{n+1}}}{n^{a_{n}}}-\frac{1}{n^{a_{n}}}}{1-\frac{1}{n^{a_{n}}}}\ ?$$
Or has somebody any other idea for this task?

Comment: We [still can have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Inconclusive_because_L_=_1) $g=1$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1} a_n < \infty$ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**0.** Note that the ratio test here is completely useless, because you do not know anything about $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ (it could even have a subsequence going to infinity).

**1.** Assume $a_n=O(\log(n)^{-1})$. Then, $$\frac{a_n^{1/2}}{\log(n)}(n^{a_n}-1)=(\exp(\log(n)a_n)-1)\frac{a_n^{1/2}}{\log(n)} \leq Ca_n^{3/2} \leq C’a_n$$ so the series converges.

**2.** Without the assumption that  $a_n=O(\log(n)^{-1})$, the series may diverge, see example below.

Take $a_{2^{p^4}}=p^{-2}$ (and zero everywhere else). Then, $\sum_n{|a_n|}=\sum_p{p^{-2}}$ converges.

However, $a_{2^{p^4}}\log(2^{p^4}) =\log(2) p^2 \rightarrow \infty$, thus $a_n \neq O((\log(n)^{-1})$.

Furthermore, 
$$\sum_n{\frac{a_n^{1/2}}{\log(n)}(n^{a_n}-1)} = \sum_p{\frac{p^{-1}}{\log(2)p^4}(2^{p^2}-1)}=\infty$$

Comment: I am afraid it is not. See the counter-example at the end.

Comment: I am looking at this and I am not able to understand why we can assume that $ a_n=O(\log(n)^{-1}) $ ?

Comment: The point is that we cannot. If $a_n$ is $O(\log(n)^{-1})$, then the second series converges. Else, it is possible that it does not converge.

Comment: We cannot? But you done this in your proposition?

Comment: I thought I had made myself clear. I proved two things: 1) in general the series needs not converge.  2) if $a_n$ is $O(\log(n)^{-1})$ then the series converges.

Comment: Ahh, my fail, yes, I didn't understand you but now I know what is going on. Moreover i had understood all, thanks for your time!